# Docker pull fails on Windows 10 in Windows Container mode

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I am trying to run docker natively on Windows 10 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-10-Client

My Windows version is :

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362.720
```

Docker version is :

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}

Docker Desktop Community : 2.2.0.5 (43884)
```

This is how the menu looks after installing : i.e. I am in "Windows Container mode"

[image]

NB : Before installing docker, I made sure "Containers" and "Hyper V" are enabled in Windows Features options.

After installing Docker, I ran this command :

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

I got this output with an error

```
C:\Users\angshuman>docker run ubuntu
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu

5bed26d33875: Pull complete
f11b29a9c730: Pull complete
930bda195c84: Pull complete
78bf9a5ad49e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bec5a2727be7fff3d308193cfde3491f8fba1a2ba392b7546b43a051853a341d
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
```

**Error:**

> time="2020-04-13T17:50:47+01:00" level=error msg="Error waiting for
>   container: failed to shutdown container: container
>   21892c2c1e7edf42bb1255809605579aa79cd0b94b1d4b6edd8fd5a55aab87d2
>   encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure
>   in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the
>   specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110): subsequent
>   terminate failed container
>   21892c2c1e7edf42bb1255809605579aa79cd0b94b1d4b6edd8fd5a55aab87d2
>   encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure
>   in a Windows system call: The virtual machine or container with the
>   specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)

Any idea how to resolve the issue please ?

**Edit: After suggestion in the answer below**

I downgraded to `2.2.0.3` with `experimental : true` and `Windows Container` *enabled*:

[image]

It **downloads** the image this time, **but** still does not run. 
Issue persists with a different error now.

**Error:**

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container 0bb1d91f5e1090bc83e8541d923484a1c07dd5adae7a7779ac0f080bd5c11815 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: Unspecified error (0x80004005)
[Event Detail: failed to run runc create/exec call for container 0bb1d91f5e1090bc83e8541d923484a1c07dd5adae7a7779ac0f080bd5c11815: exit status 1 Stack Trace:
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*container).startProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:580
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*runcRuntime).runCreateCommand
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:471
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*runcRuntime).CreateContainer
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:113
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/core/gcs.(*gcsCore).ExecProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/core/gcs/gcs.go:351
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).execProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:637
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).execProcess-fm
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:253
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.HandlerFunc.ServeMsg
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:72
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Mux).ServeMsg
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:146
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).ListenAndServe.func2.1
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:335
runtime.goexit
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333 
Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 

extra info: {"CommandArgs":["-t"],"WorkingDirectory":"/","Environment":{"HOSTNAME":"0bb1d91f5e10","PATH":"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0],"OCISpecification":{"ociVersion":"1.0.1-dev","process":{"user":{"uid":0,"gid":0},"args":["-t"],"env":["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","HOSTNAME=0bb1d91f5e10"],"cwd":"/","capabilities":{"bounding":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"effective":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"inheritable":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"permitted":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"]}},"root":{"path":"rootfs"},"hostname":"0bb1d91f5e10","mounts":[{"destination":"/proc","type":"proc","source":"proc","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev","type":"tmpfs","source":"tmpfs","options":["nosuid","strictatime","mode=755","size=65536k"]},{"destination":"/dev/pts","type":"devpts","source":"devpts","options":["nosuid","noexec","newinstance","ptmxmode=0666","mode=0620","gid=5"]},{"destination":"/sys","type":"sysfs","source":"sysfs","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","ro"]},{"destination":"/sys/fs/cgroup","type":"cgroup","source":"cgroup","options":["ro","nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/mqueue","type":"mqueue","source":"mqueue","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/shm","type":"tmpfs","source":"shm","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","mode=1777"]}],"linux":{"resources":{},"namespaces":[{"type":"mount"},{"type":"network"},{"type":"uts"},{"type":"pid"},{"type":"ipc"}],"maskedPaths":["/proc/asound","/proc/acpi","/proc/kcore","/proc/keys","/proc/latency_stats","/proc/timer_list","/proc/timer_stats","/proc/sched_debug","/proc/scsi","/sys/firmware"],"readonlyPaths":["/proc/bus","/proc/fs","/proc/irq","/proc/sys","/proc/sysrq-trigger"]},"windows":{"layerFolders":["C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\ef134f2d5748c591bf21cc2b407c49dd9be012dad5d15052bab87fc00b96444f","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\4712bcdc17711399918c44b2352c5585457db6b14285cc6b2d6b630ef4ced551","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\970a55c64e9bb9d56007e940a6ac94de463a7ad4b602f2d829f21c29b92e5369","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\79eeaef19460e004253147fa7b109664492516495d6c7d63b8631112be468f7d","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\0bb1d91f5e1090bc83e8541d923484a1c07dd5adae7a7779ac0f080bd5c11815"],"hyperv":{},"network":{"endpointList":["B5E11D3C-E874-406C-BCC0-94E1173E3E1B"],"allowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}}}}.

C:\Users\angshuman>docker run 4e5021d210f6 -it
docker: Error response from daemon: container bdd2ed406d421f00c963190cc975e5bf5f1f22b9c3536af687870257968b1fc4 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: Unspecified error (0x80004005)
[Event Detail: failed to run runc create/exec call for container bdd2ed406d421f00c963190cc975e5bf5f1f22b9c3536af687870257968b1fc4: exit status 1 Stack Trace:
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*container).startProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:580
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*runcRuntime).runCreateCommand
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:471
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*runcRuntime).CreateContainer
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:113
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/core/gcs.(*gcsCore).ExecProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/core/gcs/gcs.go:351
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).execProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:637
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).execProcess-fm
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:253
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.HandlerFunc.ServeMsg
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:72
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Mux).ServeMsg
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:146
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).ListenAndServe.func2.1
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:335
runtime.goexit
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandArgs":["-it"],"WorkingDirectory":"/","Environment":{"HOSTNAME":"bdd2ed406d42","PATH":"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0],"OCISpecification":{"ociVersion":"1.0.1-dev","process":{"user":{"uid":0,"gid":0},"args":["-it"],"env":["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","HOSTNAME=bdd2ed406d42"],"cwd":"/","capabilities":{"bounding":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"effective":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"inheritable":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"permitted":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"]}},"root":{"path":"rootfs"},"hostname":"bdd2ed406d42","mounts":[{"destination":"/proc","type":"proc","source":"proc","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev","type":"tmpfs","source":"tmpfs","options":["nosuid","strictatime","mode=755","size=65536k"]},{"destination":"/dev/pts","type":"devpts","source":"devpts","options":["nosuid","noexec","newinstance","ptmxmode=0666","mode=0620","gid=5"]},{"destination":"/sys","type":"sysfs","source":"sysfs","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","ro"]},{"destination":"/sys/fs/cgroup","type":"cgroup","source":"cgroup","options":["ro","nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/mqueue","type":"mqueue","source":"mqueue","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/shm","type":"tmpfs","source":"shm","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","mode=1777"]}],"linux":{"resources":{},"namespaces":[{"type":"mount"},{"type":"network"},{"type":"uts"},{"type":"pid"},{"type":"ipc"}],"maskedPaths":["/proc/asound","/proc/acpi","/proc/kcore","/proc/keys","/proc/latency_stats","/proc/timer_list","/proc/timer_stats","/proc/sched_debug","/proc/scsi","/sys/firmware"],"readonlyPaths":["/proc/bus","/proc/fs","/proc/irq","/proc/sys","/proc/sysrq-trigger"]},"windows":{"layerFolders":["C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\ef134f2d5748c591bf21cc2b407c49dd9be012dad5d15052bab87fc00b96444f","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\4712bcdc17711399918c44b2352c5585457db6b14285cc6b2d6b630ef4ced551","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\970a55c64e9bb9d56007e940a6ac94de463a7ad4b602f2d829f21c29b92e5369","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\79eeaef19460e004253147fa7b109664492516495d6c7d63b8631112be468f7d","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\bdd2ed406d421f00c963190cc975e5bf5f1f22b9c3536af687870257968b1fc4"],"hyperv":{},"network":{"endpointList":["C19D44B9-33F9-470A-8EC8-5C9283CE25FE"],"allowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}}}}.
```

Thanks

Angshuman

Comment: I have edited the answer to address your latest edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Sept. 2021, from [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3884#issuecomment-922408883)

> The issue should be resolved now. The CBFS Connect developers mention a fix in [v20.0.7921, released on September 8, 2021](https://www.callback.com/cbfsconnect/changelog.aspx).
>
> Software will need to update their CBFS Connect driver, though.

---

This seems to be followed by [microsoft/hcsshim issue 624](https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/issues/624)

> Windows just did an update and laid down a new copy of this driver.
>
> - Rename the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\cbfs6.sys as something else (or delete it).
> - Remove the container.
> - Reboot.

That in turn refers to [docker/for-win/issue 3884](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3884#issuecomment-533952921)

> Awesome guys at nsoftware.com just fixed the issue with their SFTP Drive v2.
> Indeed the problem was in cbfs driver. New version is working as expected and doesn't collide with Docker.

But [microsoft/hcsshim issue 790](https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/issues/790) also mentions the same error:

> The issue is present in Docker Desktop CE for windows 2.2.0.4 & 2.2.0.5
>
> A downgrade to 2.2.0.3 resolved the issue.

---

If you want to "run containers natively on Windows", the [next page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container) mentions images like `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903`

An Ubuntu image would not work in this mode, only in the Linux Container mode.

---

To summarize (before Sept. 2021):

1. Downgrade Docker Desktop to 2.2.0.3
2. Reboot machine (don't forget)
3. Delete all previously created containers / images (if any)
4. `docker run -it ubuntu` - (for some reason , shows the bash shell & then, goes out of interactive mode)
5. Run `docker run -it ubuntu` again - now, goes into interactive mode now (2nd time) and stays

This works !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211590/discussion-on-answer-by-vonc-docker-pull-fails-on-windows-10-in-windows-containe).